# Como puedo organizar un fichero por nombre en c++

Tags: c++

Amigos quien sabe como puedo organizar un fichero de acceso secuencial por nombre?

Comment: Hola César, por favor detalle mejor tu pregunta, ha sido cerrada porque no está claro exactamente que cual es tu problema, por favor lee: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio César. Tal como comenta @CarlosMuñoz, si editas el contenido de tu pregunta, es muy probable que sea reabierta y reciba la atención requerida para que te brinden una respuesta.